# SSRS - Second list is not rendered properly in browser

Tags: reporting-services, renderer

I have developed a report with basic element one list that contains two lists (one next to other)with one tablix each of them inside.
They use the same dataset, whilst the data that each list displays are based on a flag.
The first list displays the same kind of data having the flag equal to 0 whereas the second list displays the same kind of data having flag equal to 1.

Locally the report is rendered properly.
After deployed to the Report server and trying to access the same information through the browser the second list is not displayed even though the horizontal scrollbar is activated.

What might the problem be?

Comment: which report you trying to generate? and what query you are executing in dataset, Please provide those details

Comment: I do not understand your question. What do you mean by which report I am trying to generate? The one that I have developed is the answer. I need some hints that might help me. I am not so experienced with SSRS especially when it comes to the renderer and how the report fits to the browser screen